# How to pass a value to modal while opening

Tags: magento2, javascript, widget, modal-popup

Is it possible to pass a value while opening a modal(js component of magento)?
If the answer is yes, then how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do.

You have to **create an extended function** [`openModal` v2.2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js#L223) or [v2.4](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js#L228) and on this function whatever you need.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/modal/modal.js

Like:

```
 define([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function($){
            $.widget('customModel', $.mage.modal, {
                openModal: function () {
                    /* do whatever you need */
                    console.log ("My model");
                    /* call parent model */
                    this._super();
                }
            });
         return $.customModel;
        }
    );
```

Then call this js using **requirejs-config.js** on your module:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customModel: '{Vendor}_{Modulename}/js/customModel',
        }
    }
};
```

**Then use this model via your code**

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'customModel'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        customModel
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: 'Title',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Proceed'),
                class: '',
            }]
        };
        var popup = customModel(options,$('#popup-modal'));            
        $('{YourElement}').custommodal('openModal');
    }
);
```

Or, you may be use **opened** trigger. See detail https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/jquery-widgets/modal/.

I am not pretty much experience on trigger :).